React native zindex not working inside Scrollview/Flatlist
import {BlurView} from '@react-native-community/blur';

Items = () => <View style={{zIndex: 1}} />

<>
 <FlatList
    ref={flatlistRef}
    data={Array(10).fill(1)}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
      <Items />
    )}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  />

<BlurView
      style={styles.absolute}
      blurType="light"
      blurAmount={10}
      reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white">
    </BlurView>
</>


CellRendererComponent={({children}) => children}
removeClippedSubviews={false} />

I tried to add this to flatlist, but it's not working in Android and iOS.
When using the Item component outside the Flatlist, it's being rendered properly.

In React Native, managing the stacking order of components can be crucial, especially when dealing with nested structures. The zIndex property helps control which components appear on top of others.
Consider the following component structure:
// Structure
1. GrandParent
       parent
           child
2. GrandParent

Here, child is nested inside a parent, which in turn is inside 1. GrandParent. The æ2. GrandParent` is an independent component.
If you want to display something in the child component above the 2. gParent component, you should not only set the zIndex for the child but also for the topmost parent in its hierarchy, which is 1. gParent.
(Please support my comment if I could help you.)

I need to conditionally add the zIndex property, which is why i cannot use the zIndex in flatlist

You can use contentContainerStyle.

tried that it did not work. more over in my case i need only particular item in the list to have zindex applied
